# React Router: Failed to Navigate Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I setup simple route within my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import '../less/app.less';

import reducers from './reducers';

import App from './components/App';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';

// const defaultSetting = settings;
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I navigate to `localhost:8080` using webpack-dev-server I can properly show my index route. but when I navigate to `localhost:8080/login' it shows error`Cannot GET /login`.

Any solution?

Comment: The dev-server is properly configured to always return your index.html (even when you request /login)?

Comment: isn't it should always read my index.js?

Comment: try it with `<Router history={hashHistory}>` and then visit `localhost:8080/#/login` , with browserHistory I can navigate from the parent route but gives me error when I try to directly load the page

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Hi, I solved it by adding historyApiFallback: { index: 'index.html' } on my webpack config. I don't really like using hash one. but your suggestion is works too. thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the server will look for an html file at the `/login` route. So you should configure it for html5 navigation to return you `index.html` for any route it receives.

---

### EDIT:

To do so in webpack, as you suggest in the comments, you can add this to your webpack dev server config:

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

`index.html` should be the default, so no need to specify it.

Also please note that urls containing dots are still pointing to files and thus redirected to the server. For example, if you have an url such as `/search/firsname.lastname` you would need to add a handler for this.

```
historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
        {
            from: /^\/search\/.*$/,
            to: function() {
                return 'index.html';
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/454) for more info.

Comment: I add this method on my webpack config: historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
        } what do you think? is it best practice?